# Position relative to fixed - how to slide down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have my menu all set, good to go, and the JS I have at the moment doesn't have the page jumping all over the place which is good. The problem I am having, is getting my "fixed" navigation to slide up/down, instead of just appearing out of nowhere.

Currently the jQuery I have is activating a class at about 300px~ down the screen, which changes the menus position from relative to fixed.

Please note: I originally managed to get this working with static positioning, but was having a hard time with the z-index and some other elements on my site, so I would like the positioning to remain relative (not static). I also do not want to duplicate the menu in any way with javascript (have seen some examples doing that).

How can I use jquery, or css to achieve both the slidedown and slideup effect when the menus position changes to fixed?

My codes below, thankyou very much.

HTML:

```
<div class="nt-main-navigation-sticky">
    <!-- my nav, logo, etc, is in here. -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nt-main-navigation-sticky {
    position: relative;
}


.activeScroll .nt-main-navigation-sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
// get my header height
var getHeaderHeight = $('.nt-main-navigation-sticky').outerHeight();


// add/remove body class
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(window).scrollTop() > getHeaderHeight + 200) {

        $('body').addClass('activeScroll').css('padding-top', getHeaderHeight);

    } else {

        $('body').removeClass('activeScroll').css('padding-top', 0);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a transition to your css:

```
.nt-main-navigation-sticky {
    position: relative;
}


.activeScroll .nt-main-navigation-sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: -50px; // or whatever the height of the navbar
    left: 0;
    transition: top 600ms;
}
```

and js:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > getHeaderHeight + 200) {

    $('body').addClass('activeScroll').css('padding-top', getHeaderHeight);
    $('.nt-main-navigation-sticky').css('top', '0px'); // will trigger transition

} else {
    $('.nt-main-navigation-sticky').css('top', '-50px'); // will trigger transition
    $('body').removeClass('activeScroll').css('padding-top', 0);

}
```